# Veracode through an error - ASPCONFIG: Could not autodiscover 'components.config'

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, sitecore, sitecore8, veracode

I have a Veracode plugin in my VS 2013 Professional.

I have ucommerce.dll, Sitecore.Kernel and Sitecore.Analytics.dll

I set copy local true for all above dll files.

When i tried to pre-compile all the web project I'm getting a below error message

> 1>------ Pre-compile started: Project: XXXXX.Web.PQRPorta\ ------
>   1>Pre-compiling with command similar to the following:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -p
>   "C:/XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal" -v "XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal/" -fixednames -f -c
>   -d "C:/SVN/trunk/Releases/SourceCode/Source/PrecompiledWeb/XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal"
>   1>***error ASPCONFIG: Could not autodiscover 'components.config'. Make
>   sure it's present in the application folder***
>   'C:\SVN\trunk\Releases\SourceCode\Source\XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal\' or in a
>   sub folder. Paths ignored
>   ''C:\SVN\trunk\Releases\SourceCode\Source\XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal\bin',
>   'C:\SVN\trunk\Releases\SourceCode\Source\XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal\App_Data',
>   'C:\SVN\trunk\Releases\SourceCode\Source\XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal\obj''
>   1>XXXXX.Web.PQRPortal\ - 1 error, 0 warnings

Is there any configuration missing?

**Update**

I found the components.config file inside

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\Website\sitecore modules\Shell\uCommerce\Configuration

and I added the file inside the web project root directory and tried to precompile web project, now I’m getting different error error

**ASPRUNTIME: Type is not resolved for member 'Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters.ConfigurationProcessingException,Cast‌​le.Windsor, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.**

any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

The components.config is a file uCommerce need.

The configuration file should be placed somewhere below the uCommerce folder. (not sure where depend on the version) It will automatically be picked up when the application starts up.

Comment: I couldn't find such file in my VS solution, is there anyway to create a file manually?

Comment: I found the components.config file inside 

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\Website\sitecore modules\Shell\uCommerce\Configuration and I added the file inside the web project root directory and tried to precompile web project, now I’m getting different error

error ASPRUNTIME: Type is not resolved for member 'Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters.ConfigurationProcessingException,Castle.Windsor, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.

Comment: If you have a different question - you should post that separately and mark this as the answer

Comment: Looks like you miss now a Castle.*.dll

Comment: I have Castle.Windsor.dll and Castle.Core.dll but the issue still there